# how to identify if a thread has been aborted or completed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

under both aborted and completed situations, `ThreadState` will be `Stopped`.

How to differentiate between them?

Comment: You shouldn't Abort threads, and anyway you will need better state tracking than ThreadState .

Comment: I recommend using `CancellationTokenSource`, `CancellationToken`, and `Task` for best thread status results.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: what other better state tracking I can use?

Comment: It's easy. The thread completed, because no sane person would abort a thread :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original assertion is not correct.  Consider:

```
public static void TestThreadAbort()
{
    var t = new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(50000));
    t.Start();
    t.Abort();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    // Prints "Aborted"
    Console.WriteLine(t.ThreadState);
}
```

Comment: You point out the likely reason why the original caller did not see his thread state as aborted: aborting is done by the aborted thread. This means that it could take time after the Abort call before the state will reflect it.

Comment: @RobinCaron :The problem I stated seems to be a bug in earlier versions of .NET but fixed in .NET 3.5.. you can refer it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98079/thread-abort-does-not-cause-threadstate-aborted)

Answer (score 1):

Note how the `ThreadState` enum is declared:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum ThreadState { ... }
```

...Sinc it is a `[Flag]` this means a thread can be in multiple states.

[MSDN, ThreadState Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx) (emphasis added by me):

> ThreadState defines a set of all possible execution states for
>   threads. Once a thread is created, it is in at least one of the states
>   until it terminates. Threads created within the common language
>   runtime are initially in the Unstarted state, while external threads
>   that come into the runtime are already in the Running state. An
>   Unstarted thread is transitioned into the Running state by calling
>   Start. **Not all combinations of ThreadState values are valid; for
>   example, a thread cannot be in both the Aborted and Unstarted states**.

...and then goes on to say:

> **A thread can be in more than one state at a given time.** For example,
>   if a thread is blocked on a call to Wait, and another thread calls
>   Abort on the blocked thread, the blocked thread will be in both the
>   WaitSleepJoin and the AbortRequested states at the same time. In this
>   case, as soon as the thread returns from the call to Wait or is
>   interrupted, it will receive the ThreadAbortException to begin
>   aborting.
>
> The Thread.ThreadState property of a thread provides the current state
>   of a thread. Applications must use a bitmask to determine whether a
>   thread is running. Since the value for Running is zero (0), test
>   whether a thread is running by using C# code such as

```
(myThread.ThreadState & (ThreadState.Stopped | ThreadState.Unstarted)) == 0
```

Comment: my question was how to identify Aborted and Finished Threads after it's terminated.. But you have written the whole Bible.. ;)

Comment: I didn't write it ...I copied/pasted ;)  ...I don't recommend continuing to rely wholly on ThreadState. If possible, use a Task and check a CancellationToken for best results. As others have stated, ThreadState (esp. because of bit masking) is not reliable in determining the specific and accurate state.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to set a "completed" flag as the last action in your thread.  If that flag isn't set, you can assume it was aborted.  As @Chris Shain points out below, you have to be careful where you put it, though, since in the case of a thread abort, you'll get a `ThreadAbortException` in your thread, so if you put it in the `finally` clause, it will get set even in the case of a thread abort.

Comment: Putting it in a finally clause would cause it to be set even if a ThreadAbortException was thrown

Answer (score 0):

When a thread is aborted . You get ThreadAbortException on your thread.
This can help you in differentiating.